# Suggestion (with/in) regard to

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the difference in the meaning/usage of these two phrases ?

> Suggestion in regard to
>
> Suggestion with regard to

Googling yields results showing both phrases being used but I couldn't understand the difference in their meaning.

A Few sentences Copied from google:

Another interesting suggestion in regard to that voluntary Socialism.

Looking at some of the suggestions with regard to the maximum levels permitted under the reports.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning between ***in, with, having** [regard to something]*, nor is there [any significant preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plans+*+regard+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cplans%20%2A%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bplans%20with%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplans%20in%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplans%20without%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0) between the first two. But note that it's almost always ***in** respect **of*** or ***with** respect **to*** if you switch to that alternative to ***regard***.

Comment: And do not forget **as regards something** remembering that the aforementioned _regards_ are nouns whilst this one is a verb.

Comment: @Mv Log: Good point. But although it doesn't sound *ridiculously* "off" to me, we almost never encounter plural ***regards*** in OP's construction ***in/with** xxx **to** [something]*, nor do we ever see the "singular" version after ***as***.